# Gitlab pages not serving page under new domain

Tags: ssl, dns, gitlab, domain-name

I have followed [Setting up GitLab Pages with CloudFlare Certificates](https://about.gitlab.com/2017/02/07/setting-up-gitlab-pages-with-cloudflare-certificates/), and everything seems to be as expected. I can see the following in my gitlab pages:

[image]

But when I open https://ethprobe.com, I cant see the page. I can see the page under https://amarsh.hk.gitlab.io/ethprobe (which mans, it is being served correctly). Any clue on what couldl be wrong?

My cloudfare DNS entries look like:

[image]